# How to access object variable in visible? method graphql-ruby

Tags: graphql, authorization, graphql-ruby

I am trying to hide query class from schema from a user to whom fields are not visible.
There are various levels of Users based on permissions.
I can use `visible?(ctx)` method on class level where I have fields visibility is decided based on context. But in some places it is based on the `object`'s column/field value too.
How do I access `object` in the `visible?(ctx)` method. Or is there any way of globally hiding the class if no fields are accessible(Otherwise the Gquery client throws warnings of No fields defined).